# I can't rotate my square towards the mouse p5.js, keeping it in the center

Tags: javascript, class, rotation, mouse, p5.js

Well, I am making a tank game. In this very basic question(hoping it'll be a basic answer) all I wanna know how to do is, pointing my tank towards my mouse. The code in my `Tank` class is:

```
class Tank {  
  constructor(x, y, size) {
    this.startX = x;
    this.startY = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.speed = 2;
    this.rotation = 0;
    this.pos = this.getPos();
    this.exp = 5;
    this.level = 1;
    this.expRequired = 100;
    this.smallerChosen = 30;
    this.vel = createVector(0, 0);
    this.accelaration = 1;
  }

  getPos() {
    return createVector(this.startX, this.startY);
  }

  drawTurret() {
    let x = this.pos.x + this.size / 4;
    let y = this.pos.y + this.size / 4;
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    rect(x, y, this.size * 1.5, this.size * 1.5, this.size / 4);
    fill(0, 255, 0)
    rect(x + this.size / 2 + this.size / 10, y - this.size, this.size / 4, this.size);
  }

  drawBase() {
    fill(0, 220, 0)
    rect(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.size * 2, this.size * 2)
  }

  show() {
    push();
    rotate(this.rotation);
    this.drawBase();
    this.drawTurret();
    rotate(-this.rotation);
    this.size = mainTankSize + (this.exp / 3) * this.level / (this.smallerChosen / 10);
    pop()
  }

  move() {
    var newvel = createVector(mouseX - width / 2, mouseY - height / 2);
    newvel.setMag(this.speed);
    this.vel.lerp(newvel, this.accelaration / 30)
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
  }

  increaseExp(exp) {
    this.exp += exp;
    let color;
    if (exp >= this.expRequired / 5) {
      color = 255, 255, 0
    }
    else {
      color = 255
    }
    let s = "+" + exp;
  }

  eats(obj) {
    let d = p5.Vector.dist(this.pos, obj.pos);
    let area = PI * obj.r * obj.r;
    let exp = sqrt(area / PI);

    if (d - this.size <= this.size - obj.r - 50) {
      if (this.pos.y - obj.pos.y < 0) {
        return false;
      }
      this.increaseExp(exp)
      return true;
    }
    else if (d - this.size <= this.size + obj.r && this.pos.y - obj.pos.y < 0) {
      if (this.pos.x - obj.pos.x > 0) {
        return false
      }
      this.increaseExp(exp)
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

That is it! And I have done literally everything as you can see up there but when I rotate the tank change the `this.rotation` variable according to `mouseX`, it does rotate, it surely does but... It ruins everything, like, in another file I've written alot of code which aligns the tank to the center and changes the view using the `translate()` function and zooms out using the `scale()` function. Everything was and is working perfectly but if I even hard-code and change the `this.rotation` variable, everything stops working all over again!

So, what I need is, some *really **really*** smart dude shows up and tells me or shares some code to change the `this.rotation` variable without ruining the entire website.

Thanks in advance - BSK Animations

Comment: can you share your `setup()` and `draw()` function. I am having hard time interpreting/testing your code with only the class. You might have some problems with those functions

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the functions `push()` and `pop()`, use `push()` right before you rotate and `pop()` after you draw.

[p5 reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the angle to:

```
atan2(mouseY - this.pos.y, mouseX - this.x);
```